# Как перенести целиком mongodb с windows в Kubuntu, имея только доступ к ФС HDD с windows, на которой стоит БД?

Tags: linux, windows, mongodb

Пользовался Windows 10, на ней стояла mongodb.

Windows сломалась, но файловая система цела и я взял из неё папку MongoData. Есть так же возможность перенести папку с исполняемыми файлами БД, если там лежит что-то важное.

Не уверен, что я поставил mongodb адекватным образом, ведь этот процесс под windows очень смахивал на какие-то костыли и я его не помню.

Теперь я установил Kubuntu и мне нужно снова установить эту БД и дополнительно перенести коллекции и настройки с жёсткого диска.

Как мне это сделать имея только папки с файлами mongodb?

В линуксе я относительно молодой

Содержимое MongoData:

```
Kubuntu:~/MongoData$ tree        
.
├── collection-0--1647353232700239766.wt
├── collection-0-1765684691600950404.wt
├── collection-0--2024320138168364518.wt
├── collection-0-463494539637232172.wt
├── collection-0-5948112813629615815.wt
├── collection-2-463494539637232172.wt
├── collection-4-463494539637232172.wt
├── diagnostic.data
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-20T17-19-31Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-20T17-25-46Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-21T11-51-44Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-21T11-54-07Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-21T13-16-46Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-21T13-24-45Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-21T13-26-41Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-21T13-30-51Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-21T13-34-57Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-21T13-38-16Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-21T15-24-59Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-21T20-37-56Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-22T18-33-07Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-23T13-36-21Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-23T14-23-55Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-23T14-24-42Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-23T14-25-11Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-23T14-25-30Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-23T14-25-59Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-23T14-40-02Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-23T14-40-37Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-23T16-00-36Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-23T16-21-43Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-23T17-18-36Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-23T20-41-22Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2019-12-31T21-55-50Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-01T09-25-23Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-01T15-06-39Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-01T17-25-43Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-02T14-39-41Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-02T21-31-57Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-02T21-33-44Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-02T21-46-49Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-03T12-30-35Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-04T09-46-01Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-05T20-58-10Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-07T09-46-28Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-07T20-52-07Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-07T22-46-48Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-08T09-45-05Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-09T15-22-39Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-10T08-18-37Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-10T17-07-53Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-10T20-35-22Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-11T11-38-24Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-13T13-39-20Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-13T19-48-37Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-19T08-17-14Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-19T08-21-28Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-01-23T15-22-44Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-02-04T13-10-41Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-02-04T14-41-54Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-02-05T15-47-52Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-02-06T15-27-15Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-02-07T18-51-31Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-02-08T11-26-37Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-02-08T13-47-22Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-02-08T16-36-56Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-02-09T10-52-43Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-02-09T16-11-28Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-02-09T19-03-05Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-02-21T22-34-55Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-02-25T11-42-52Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-03-01T12-16-33Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-03-02T17-45-15Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-03-02T19-24-59Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-03-05T13-59-52Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-03-14T16-20-29Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-03-16T10-39-49Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-03-16T18-41-13Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-03-17T13-09-45Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-03-18T13-59-57Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-03-19T12-05-36Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-03-20T16-35-03Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-03-22T13-07-04Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-03-24T19-58-19Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-03-25T11-40-05Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-03-29T19-10-30Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-03-30T18-14-08Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-04-04T15-36-23Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-04-20T12-21-01Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-04-21T10-29-16Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-04-23T17-06-05Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-01T15-17-13Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-01T17-34-24Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-02T22-15-56Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-04T18-52-55Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-04T18-53-20Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-04T18-53-34Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-04T18-53-56Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-04T18-59-46Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-08T18-00-52Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-08T18-10-49Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-08T19-33-34Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-12T16-52-22Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-12T18-02-11Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-12T18-02-24Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-12T18-03-40Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-15T19-11-25Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-24T13-53-39Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-25T22-18-14Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-28T08-30-50Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-30T12-13-30Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-05-31T22-44-58Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-01T11-30-05Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-01T11-56-39Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-01T16-48-28Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-01T19-49-50Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-01T19-50-10Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-03T15-54-02Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-03T18-04-25Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-05T20-51-35Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-07T15-59-10Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-08T15-48-23Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-08T15-49-07Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-13T14-07-59Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-13T14-59-18Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-13T21-49-32Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-14T17-13-22Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-17T21-50-30Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-19T13-06-36Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-19T13-08-16Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-19T16-05-39Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-20T16-33-21Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-21T14-31-43Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-22T09-28-28Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-23T20-59-35Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-24T16-08-39Z-00000
│   ├── metrics.2020-06-24T18-01-28Z-00000
│   └── metrics.2020-06-24T18-53-16Z-00000
├── index-1--1647353232700239766.wt
├── index-1-1765684691600950404.wt
├── index-1--2024320138168364518.wt
├── index-1-463494539637232172.wt
├── index-1-5948112813629615815.wt
├── index-2--2024320138168364518.wt
├── index-3-463494539637232172.wt
├── index-5-463494539637232172.wt
├── index-6-463494539637232172.wt
├── journal
│   ├── WiredTigerLog.0000000052
│   ├── WiredTigerPreplog.0000000001
│   └── WiredTigerPreplog.0000000002
├── _mdb_catalog.wt
├── mongod.lock
├── sizeStorer.wt
├── storage.bson
├── WiredTiger
├── WiredTigerLAS.wt
├── WiredTiger.lock
├── WiredTiger.turtle
└── WiredTiger.wt

2 directories, 158 files
```

Содержимое папки Mongodb:

```
nikel@nikel-Kubuntu:/mnt/disk_c/Program Files (x86)/Mongodb$ tree
.
├── 1.ico
├── bsondump.exe
├── Install-Compass.ps1
├── mongod.exe
├── mongod.pdb
├── mongodump.exe
├── mongo.exe
├── mongoexport.exe
├── mongofiles.exe
├── mongoimport.exe
├── mongo.pdb
├── mongorestore.exe
├── mongos.exe
├── mongos.pdb
├── mongostat.exe
└── mongotop.exe

0 directories, 16 files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы начал с того, что подцепил диск (физический) на котором лежат базы данных к компу, на котором вы поставили *Kubuntu*.

После этого установил в убунте драйвер NTFS (я надеюсь, БД Ваша лежала **не** на FAT32 ?)
Насколько я помню, он называется ntfs-3g и есть во всех дистрибутивах.

Затем прописал бы в /etc/fstab дополнительную строчу вида

```
/dev/sda2 /mnt/disk_c ntfs-3g rw,user,users,gid=users,fmask=113,dmask=002,locale=ru_RU.UTF-8 0 0
```

Где вместо */dev/sda2 /mnt/disk_c* надо написать то, что есть у Вас.

Потом бы перегрузил комп и установил *mongodb*. Во время установи указал бы ей в  качестве каталога с БД тот каталог, который лежит у Вас на виндовозном диске.

Я на 75% уверен, что это сработает. Ну а если нет - тогда придётся думать более тщательно :-)

Comment: Первый этап я уже выполнил. Кубунту я ставил на новый хард, и он вместе с хардом с виндой подключен к моему компу. Хард с виндой успешно открылся и я перенёс из него эти файлы на хард с линуксом. Кстати хард с виндой как-то по особенному примонтировался: file system: fuseblk, mounted on: /media/nikel/C02AD1022AD0F5FE, mounted from: /dev/sdb2

Comment: Я точно не знаю какая ФС. Важно: мне хочется тот диск с виндой использовать под другие цели, поэтому устанавливать бд на него не подходит, и делать это с помощью apt я не умею. И боюсь даже если это возможно, что при установке возникнут конфликты и не дай бог файлы перезатрутся

Comment: Строчку прописал, похоже, что всё в порядке и по поводу ntfs вы не ошиблись. Драйвер оказался предустановленным и моя ФС ntfs

Comment: @Николай - " file system: fuseblk" - Это означает, что монтирование было выполнено не стандартным ядерным драйвером, а драйвером пространства пользователя. И это странно... Вы куда дисковод виндовозный диск прицепили - на SATA, или через USB ?

Comment: @Николай - "устанавливать бд на него не подходит"  - Так и НЕ надо этого делать! Пусть СУБД встанет куда надо, как скажет apt-gert.

Comment: @Николай - "делать это с помощью apt я не умею" - Разумеется, это делается  НЕ apt-get! Ситуация вот какая: когда будет запускаться сам SQL сервер, ему нужнго знать, где лежат файлы с данными. Должен быть какой-то конфигурационный фай, где сервер хранит все свои настройки. Что это за файл и как его править - должно юыть написано в инструкции к серверу БД.